# PHP sessions - setting in iframe and retrieving

Tags: php, iframe, session-variables

I have a HTML form that is sent to a PHP page to process. I need to add some functionality to the form and need to set a session variable in the HTML form. I cannot change the HTML page to PHP and so have set a session in a PHP page and included this into the form as an Iframe. When the page loads the session var is set but I cannot retrieve this session in the process PHP page, the session is empty. Can anyone assist?

Code that sets session in iframe:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start(); // start a session
$code = rand(1000, 9999); //create a random number between 1000 and 9999
$_SESSION['code'] = $code; //add the random number to session 'code'
```

Code in process.php page where i need to retrieve session:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);
```

Can anyone assist?

EDIT:

I have just realised that this works in IE but not in firefox or chrome - strange.

Comment: is the iframe hosted on another domain?

Comment: no its on the same domain

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some extra work to make sure the cookie with the session ID in it is shared with the iframe. Note that for security reasons this is only possible if the iframe is on the same domain as the container website.

Comment: what extra work exactly?  The php file that the iframe links to is on the same domain.